# How to prevent overriding javascript intellisense in visual studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to work with some html file.
I want to use the jquery intellisense for better work.I do the following step:

- In the Javascript intellisense Setting, choose Implicit (Web) group,
  and add a reference `E:\Web\js\jquery.dev.js` (this is an uncompressed, *development* version)
- Refresh the reference from menu > Edit > intellisense > Refresh

It works fine. As I type `$.` it will suggest some word like `$.acceptData(elem)` with an extra docs comment `"Determines whether an object can have data"`. 
But when I work with a html file that have `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` tag, the VS will load this data and *override* all intellisense I have above.
When I type `$.`, it display `$.acceptData(a)` with no javascript docs, it has been override by the compressed version
So, how can I still have the word suggestion without remove the script tag?

Comment: if you want instelliance for only particular script file.you can /// <reference path="jquery.dev.js" /> to the script file

Comment: Place reference tag after <script> tag? Still not work

Comment: place above mentioned reference tag in a file named as `_references.js`